# Priority of logical operations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

I need to create a truth table for the expression
$$\overline{YZ\implies X}$$ Negation must be made at the beginning, before the rest of the actions, or at the very end? In the case of the negation of individual variables, then I understand that first it is done, and then the rest of the action?

Comment: It looks as if you are applying negation (by the overline) to the entire expression (so you are applying negation "at the very end").  But you have asked the Question, so you are considered the expert about what you wish to ask.  Can you create the truth table for part of the expression?  Once you have the truth table for the expression before applying negation, surely applying negation to get the final truth table will be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the overline covers the whole expression $YZ \Rightarrow X$, the negation is applied to that whole latter expression. That is,  you need to first figure out the value of $YZ \Rightarrow X$, and then negate that. So it is the last operation you do for this expression.